# Firefox -createprofile "example" doesn't create profile [Centos 7.6]

Tags: centos, terminal, firefox

I am trying to create new profile via Terminal for firefox and am using this command:

```
firefox -createprofile 'profile'
```

It looks like everything is fine, but I can't find any new file by using `ls | grep "profile"`

While using

```
./firefox -profilemanager
```

Firefox is openning on blank page, by checking in *help -> Troubleshooting information -> Profile directory*, there is always same directory / name of folder.

By using

```
firefox -profile "profile"
```

the same thing happens.

I have tried to use uppercase version as well as lowercase; both work and open Firefox.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried using `firefox -P` or -p , there is also no visual difference (as how is firefox acting, where redirecting and what profile applying)

Also by using `ls ~.mozilla/firefox` and opening with VI profiles.ini , I can see that there is only one profile there (which was created by default)

My current directory is `/home/username/.mozilla/firefox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-createprofile` is not a valid command-line argument for starting Firefox.
To create a new profile, you start by launching the Profile Manager by running `firefox --ProfileManager`. If you already have an instance of Firefox running (there could be an errant process running in the background; check this with `ps -u`) , you can add the `--no-remote` to start a new instance:

```
firefox --ProfileManager --no-remote
```

You can then start the *Create Profile Wizard* by clicking on the *Create Profile* button.  This will create a new profile in `~/.mozilla/firefox/`.

Comment: This solution helped me, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Accepting the answer was sufficient thanks. Later (when you get more reputation), you'll also be able to upvote answers. On that note, have an upvote for clearly explaining your problem in the question body - and for showing what you've already tried/researched. Welcome to [unix.se]!

Comment: Thanks. The `-P profilename` argument (by itself) used to start a new instance until a few versions ago; now `-no-remote` is required... The current [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) are very confusing; they imply that `-new-instance` is enough, but it still reuses the existing instance for me.